# $X$ is basically disconnected if every cozero-set has an open closure.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

a space $X$  is said to be **extremally disconnected** if every open set has an open closure.

$X$ is **basically disconnected**  if every cozero-set has an open closure.

hence any extremally disconnected space is basically disconnected. The converse fails.

> 1: Is every  open subspace of an extermally disconnected space  extermally disconnected? Is it true for basically disconnected?
>
> 2:In an extermally disconnected space,  are any two disjoint zero-sets completely seperated?
>
> ( Or even in an  bacically disconnected space,  are any two disjoint cozero-sets  completely seperated?)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes for extremally disconnected, and the proof is really straightforward, so you should think about it. Not necessarily for basically disconnected I think. A cozero set in the subspace does not have to be the intersection of a cozero set in the whole space and the subspace. It is if the open subspace is $C^*$-embedded or if the subspace itself is cozero in the whole space. I would take a basically connected space that is not extremally connected and try to find a counterexample.

   Every two disjoint zero sets are completely separated and this has nothing to do with extremal or basic disconnectedness. If $A = f^{-1}(0)$ and $B = g^{-1}(0)$ and they are disjoint, consider $x \mapsto f(x) / (f(x) + g(x))$.